# VHDL: find integer range by the width of corresponding width of std_logic_vector

Tags: vhdl

I have a signal `std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0)`. I need an integer signal which gets the value from the vector. How do I decide the range of this integer signal?

Comment: What's the signal's name? for `signal A:  std_logic_vector ( WIDTH - 1 downto 0);` then `signal indx:    integer range A'RANGE;` using the predefined array attribute 'RANGE. Note you could `signal indx: integer range WIDTH - 1 downto 0);` as well or `signal indx:    integer range A'REVERSE_RANGE;`, etc.

Comment: Thank you @user1155120.

Answer (score 1):

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity TEST is
  generic(WIDTH : integer := 8);
  port(
    S : in  std_logic_vector(WIDTH-1 downto 0));
end entity TEST;

architecture A of TEST is
  subtype I is integer range S'range;
  subtype T is integer range 0 to 2**WIDTH-1;
begin
  process is
  begin
    report "I: " & I'image(I'val(I'low)) & "; " & I'image(I'val(I'high));
    report "T: " & T'image(T'val(T'low)) & "; " & T'image(T'val(T'high));
    wait;
  end process;
end architecture A;
```

Result:

```
> # ** Note: I: 0; 7
> #    Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /test
> # ** Note: T: 0; 255
> #    Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /test
```

Comment: Crystal clear. Thank you @EML. Is it possible to find out WIDTH instead of getting it from generic input?